# Set values of user input via JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a little game and want the user to set the width and height of it themself.

```
...
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("800");
    dialog.setTitle("Es war ein Mal...");
    dialog.setHeaderText("... ein Spieler der sich ein Spielfeld auserwählte.");
    dialog.setContentText("Wie breit soll das Spielfeld sein?");
    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent()){
        public static int W = result.get();
    }

    scene = new Scene(createContent());
    stage.setTitle("Le Minesweeper!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private static final int Felder_Gr = 40;
//private static int W = 800;
//private static int H = 600;

private static final int X_FelderS = W / Felder_Gr;
private static final int Y_FelderS = H / Felder_Gr;
...
```

With //private static int W = 800; I set it static but want it to be replaced with the user input in line 10.

Comment: Width and height of what, and it might be better UX to allow the user to just resize the window versus setting it in a text field on startup.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your code as follow:

```
public static double W;
private static double X_FelderS;
private static final int Felder_Gr = 40; 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("800");
    dialog.setTitle("Es war ein Mal...");
    dialog.setHeaderText("... ein Spieler der sich ein Spielfeld auserwählte.");
    dialog.setContentText("Wie breit soll das Spielfeld sein?");
    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
     if (result.isPresent()) {
             W = Double.parseDouble(result.get());
             X_FelderS = W / Felder_Gr; 
        }

        scene = new Scene(createContent());
        stage.setTitle("Le Minesweeper!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
```

Comment: Sadly it give me an empty field.